# Trying to understand Git Branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I'm starting with Git and I don't fully understand how branches work. 
I started a basic project and I did the following:

1. start in '**master**' local branch, create 2 files: **1.txt** and **2.txt**. Add those files. Commit and Push. => origin/master has those 2 files now.
2. create a work in progress branch (wip) from 'local/master = head/master' => wip_12_pushed (it should have files 1 & 2)
3. still in local master, create two more **files (3,4)**) but **don't even add them.**
4. create a branch from 'local/master' => **wip_34_not_added** (I guess this should still have just files 1,2... as 3,4 have not been added)
5. in local master, create two more **files (5,6)**, add them, commit them and **push them**.
6. create branch from 'local/master'=> **wip_files_56_pushed** (so this should have files 1,2,5,6 pushed)
7. in local master, create two more **files (7,8)**, add them, commit them but don't push them
8. create local branch from 'local/master => **wip_78_committed_only** (so this should have files 1,2,5,6 (all pushed), not sure about 5,6. Should they appear in the new branch as committed as well?)

The issue I'm having to understand is that when I am switching to those different branches, I cannot really see any difference on my windows command line? and even going to my windows folder, all files are still there, so **how do I know which file belongs to which branch?**

Even more, I **switched to branch 'wip_56_pushed'**, which was created before doing anything with files 7 and 8. I then did `git push --set-upstream origin wip_56_pushed` from that branch and **somehow the files 7 and 8** which were in state of commit only in local/master and 'wip78_committed' **were pushed into the remote origin/master as well?** I was expecting this 'wip_56_pushed' branch to have no idea about the new files?

Comment: please provide the exact commands you issued.

Comment: The only command I used `git push --set-upstream origin wip_56_pushed`. All other operations were done with TortoiseGit in Windows UI. Basically, I don't know where I can see which files belong to which branch (as all are in the same windows folder). And I don't understand why when I pushed branch 'wip_56_pushed' with the command above my origin/master received files 7 and 8 as well (which were commited but in other branches only)?

Comment: Ah, I think I know your problem now.

Comment: Besides Vampire's answer, just keep in mind that there is a lot of historical baggage about branch names so there are 40 gazillion configuration options you can set or tweak, most of which you want to avoid as much as possible. Keep the local name `foo` matching the upstream `origin/foo` which is `foo` on the other Git on `origin` and you'll be much happier.

Comment: Thanks torek, I spent almost the whole of today and I was still having problems when trying to merge from one local branch to a remote branch and switching branches). I'll try to keep it as simple as possible as in our project we don't need anything fancy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git push --set-upstream origin wip_56_pushed` does not push `wip_56_pushed` to `origin/master`, but to `origin/wip_56_pushed`. As you added files 7 and 8 to master before and probably pushed it, they are present in `origin/master` of course. If you want to push your local `wip_56_pushed` to `origin/master`, do `git push --set-upstream origin wip_56_pushed:master`.

As to which files belong to which branches, this is simple. If you have branch X checked out, all files that are not untracked (`git status`) are part of the branch you have checked out.

Comment: Thanks, I've been practicing and understanding a little bit more. Two more doubts: 1-where are the local files stored for the different branches (as they might be different)? 2- I kept the origin/master and I created a new origin/78_branch (in this branch, I pushed two new files -7,8). If I am on my local/master now, how can I pull and merge the changes from origin/78_branch? I'm doing `git merge origin/78_branch master` and I get 'already up-to-date' (but I'm not getting the new files 7,8). If I do `git pull origin 78_branch` I get already uptodate as well. branch->FETCH_HEAD.But no new files

Comment: **1** Inside `.git` Git stores very efficiently all the diffs of your files in `objects`. That's the sense of a VCS, wouldn't make too much sense if all files of all branches would be there at once. ;-) **2** Hard to answer without commands to reproduce your situation or your repo. Especially as you before said you already added 7 and 8 to master.

Comment: 1. I see, thanks. 2- I started a new project from scratch after your 1st explanation. In this one, I just created a master, added some files (1 to 4), then I created a branch from there, kept adding more files in the new branch (5-8), I pushed all those files to a new remote branch (78_remote). And now, locally I checked out the original master (which has files 1-4). What I'm trying is to merge origin/78_remote with local/master and get the new files (5-8) but the commands I'm doing just say local/master is up-to-date, which is not correct as there are files missing...

Comment: Are you sure you did push that branch and not only committed to the local branch? Do `git log origin/78-remote`, `git log 78-remote` and `git log master`. And if you want to learn and understand git I recommend using the command-line for this. You can use the GUI later on still if you prefer. This also has the advantage that you can post the commands you did here. ;-)

Comment: Yes, the files are on the server (checking the website): origin/78-remote (files 1-8), origin/master (files 1-4 only). local/master (files 1-4 only). The `git merge` and `git pull` command I run don't bring the file from origin/78-remote (I guess I'm not using the correct syntax?, but I can't figure it out)

Comment: Note: `git rebase origin/78-remote` brought the files that were missing!, but file 1-4 had conflicts and from the command line I don't know how to fix. so I did `git rebase --abort` for now. I was expecting a PULL or MERGE from 'origin/78-remote' to behave the way 'rebase' did, but not sure why those 2 commands say local/master up-to-date... when I'm pointing to 'origin/78-remote'. Difficult to understand...

Comment: Vampire, thanks for the help. I still cannot make the merge to work. But I'll see if I can understand it, or I'll ask a new question for that specific feature. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

how you are switching from one branch to another branch ? you used many times push.. which may not be needed at this point, but not mentioned checkout even single time, which is used mainly to switch between branch .. can you share output of following

1 ) `git reflog`

2) `git ls-tree --name-only master`

3) `git ls-tree --name-only < branch name >` ( share results for each branch )

Comment: I was in the correct branch at the time to do the push. I was switching them via the tortoise front end, but that's doing a `git branch checkout` under the hood. There were still issues with things missing in some of the branches when I was trying to merge, but for now, I'm not trying to create many branches until I understand that fully.

Comment: oh..ok, please use `git rev-list remote_name /master ^$(git rev-list master --all)` to get the difference between 2 remote and local...which always cause issues..use remote branch name from `git branch -r`

Comment: Cheers man, I'll take a note to compare next time I see strange issues.